# Utilities.formatString not working as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, string-formatting

I wrote a small script in order to have an incremental ID composed by string character by using the function Utilities.formatString

Example: RQ001 -> RQ002 --> RQ00n

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "RQ001";
  var res = str.substring(2, 5);    'ok
  res=Number(res)+1;    'ok
  res=res.toString();   'ok
  res = "RQ" & Utilities.formatString("000", res);  'not working }
```

The results is "0".

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues. You need to use "+" for string concatenation and your method for creating your string isn't properly returning "002" like you want.

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "RQ001";
  var res = Number(str.substring(2, 5)) + 1;
      res = "000" + String(res);
      res = "RQ" + res.substring(res.length - 3, res.length);
}
```

Use `substring()` to format your string's number and then append the `"RQ"` to the beginning afterwards.

You can also format the function to take the original key as a parameter. This way, you can say something like `newKey = incrementKey(oldKey)`.

```
function incrementKey(str) {
  var res = Number(str.substring(2, 5)) + 1;
      res = "000" + String(res);
      res = "RQ" + res.substring(res.length - 3, res.length);
      return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

& is not string concatenation operator. Use "+" instead.